# Turn on VM from iap

Tags: google-cloud-platform, in-app-purchase

How can I turn on an instance that is turned off in my google cloud project using IAP?
I was looking from the iap configurations but I can't find any that is to turn on a vm, is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

The IAP functionality is all about controlling centralized access to your cloud-based and on-premises applications and VMs running on Google Cloud (emphasis on running). It is a security feature if you will and you better off using [gcloud command](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/instances/start) for what you need to do.